# The int function and its parameters

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm working on [this series of problems](https://github.com/zhiwehu/Python-programming-exercises/blob/master/100%2B%20Python%20challenging%20programming%20exercises.txt).

I do not understand question 11 and the way `int()` is being used. I understand that converting `x` directly into an `int` causes the loss of some zeroes so doing that was out of the question but I'm not understanding what

```
intp = int(p,2)
```

is suppose to be doing. Printing out `intp` I get the following values, `4,3,10,9`. How is that at all related to `0100,0011,1010,1001`? Also why are zeros lost in the first place?

Question 11
Level 2

> Question: Write a program which accepts a sequence of comma separated
>   4 digit binary numbers as its input and then check whether they are
>   divisible by 5 or not. The numbers that are divisible by 5 are to be
>   printed in a comma separated sequence.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> 0100,0011,1010,1001
> ```
>
> Then the output should be:
>
> ```
> 1010
> ```
>
> Notes: Assume the data is input by console.
>
> Hints: In case of input data being supplied to the question, it should
>   be assumed to be a console input.

```
value = []
items=[x for x in raw_input().split(',')]
for p in items:
    print p
    intp = int(p, 2)
    print intp
    if not intp%5:
        value.append(p)

print ','.join(value)
```

Comment: Do you know what binary is?

Comment: read the python man page for `int`

Answer (score 1):

To convert binary number into Decimal, we have to use the python built-in **int** function, which takes the binary number and the base of number system as an argument. 
Example:

```
>>> p='1010'
>>> c=int(p,2)
>>> print c
    10
```

Answer (score 0):

int() function in Python and Python3 converts a number in a given base to decimal.

Syntax :int(string, base)

Parameter :

string: consists of 1's and 0's
base : (integer value) base of the number.
Returns :

Returns an integer value, which is equivalent
of binary string in the given base.

for more information [Click here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-int-function/)

Answer (score -1):

As the grumpy comments up above suggested, the int function takes a second argument, which is the base of the conversion.  So it's taking the base 2 (binary) variable bound to p and turning it to a base-10 int, i.e., normal human.

Comment: What it turns it into is just a number. Numbers don't have any base, they only have a base when you input or output them.

Comment: Excellent, I think I understand now. The 2 in int(p, 2) is referring to the binary conversion, the result of which will be either (4,3,10,9) depending on which value I'm calculating and that resultant number is the base-10 which is essentially a human translation of (0100,0011,1010,1001) but the math applied to either (intp%5) will give me the same result just so happens I have to use the base-10.

Answer (score -1):

```
value = []
items=[x for x in input().split(',')]
for p in items:
    intp = int(p, 2)
    value.append(intp)

for x in value:
    if x%5==0:
        print(bin(x))
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to clarify your answer.

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.